# Add elements to numpy array at desired locations based on reference array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have some experiment data, with data logged with a periodic time interval. If the value of the measured property was 0, then the corresponding time stamp and the value of the property (0) were not logged. However, for analysis purposes, I need to add a 0 to the measured property array at the corresponding times when its value was 0.

The following simple example shows my problem

```
loggedTimes = numpy.array([0,    10,   20,  40,  50, 80, 90, 100])
property    = numpy.array([1500, 2000, 500, 75,  60, 45, 37, 0])
```

All possible logging times were:

```
allTimes = numpy.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

Therefore, at times 30, 60 and 70, the value of the property was 0. Thus, I need to add a 0 at the corresponding locations in the property array such that the result is:

```
allTimes          = numpy.array([0,    10,   20,  30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
propertyCorrected = numpy.array([1500, 2000, 500, 0,  75, 60, 0,  0,  45, 37, 0])
```

Is there a smart way to do this without using loops. This is because my experiment data is very large, and I have multiple experiment runs, so loops would be too slow, particularly if I need to reload the experiment data from the text files.

If it helps, all times and property values are integers.

Thanks!

Comment: Changing the size of numpy arrays is a relatively slow operation.  If you have a large amount of data, you might want to reconsider your data structure at a deeper level, because any system that's based on changing the sizes of your arrays is likely to be slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say if both the *allTimes* and *loggedTimes* arrays are sorted, this would be something you can start with:

```
propertyCorrected  = np.zeros(allTimes.size)
propertyCorrected [np.searchsorted(allTimes, loggedTimes)] = property
propertyCorrected 
#array([ 1500.,  2000.,   500.,     0.,    75.,    60.,     0.,     0.,
#          45.,    37.,     0.])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Nice and simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to accomplish the same.

```
final_vals = np.zeros(allTimes.size)
final_vals[np.in1d(allTimes, loggedTimes)] = property
final_vals
array([ 1500.,  2000.,   500.,     0.,    75.,    60.,     0.,     0.,
      45.,    37.,     0.])
```

Though upon a cursory test of performance it would appear that `np.searchsorted` has significantly better performance.

Comment: This answer is also useful if someone needs to do the something similar where the arrays are not sorted.